# Settings to not suspend on lid close do nothing

Tags: settings

[image]

Still when I close the lid the laptop suspends.

How do I stop Ubuntu from suspending, at all, ever? It wouldn't be so annoying if it were possible to wake from a suspend.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: @Mitch OS: Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64, Kernel: 3.11.0-12-generic